# GraphQL: Unable to match type definition (TypeName{name='Long'})

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I am just learning graphql using Springboot and was trying the example from this link https://bezkoder.com/spring-boot-graphql-mysql-jpa/. Now I have encountered a problem and not able to understand why it's throwing this error.

Can someone please help me to point out what mistake I have made ?

**Error:** `graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaClassScannerError: Unable to match type definition (TypeName{name='Long'}) with java type (class java.lang.Long): No TypeDefinition for type name Long`

**author.graphqls**

```
type Author {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    age: Int
}

# Root
type Query {
    findAuthorById(id: Long): Author!
    findAllAuthors: [Author]!
    countAuthors: Long!
}

# Root
type Mutation {
    createAuthor(name: String!, age: Int): Author!
}
```

**Author.java**

```
@Entity
public class Author {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "age")
  private Integer age;
```

Comment: https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Scalars

Answer (score 1):

The GraphQL spec only specifies Int, Float, String, Boolean, and ID as primitive types (aka "scalars"). However, it does allow for extending this set of scalar types. The implementation of the GraphQL specification you're using, GraphQL Java, doesn't provide a `Long` scalar type by default. You could set up your own but in this case I think it'd be easier to use the [graphql-java-extended-scalars](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-extended-scalars) package. It's pretty easy to set up. Note that it provides a `GraphQLLong` scalar type def which represents `java.lang.Long`. If you don't want to use the name "GraphQLLong" for this type, you can alias it like so:

```
GraphQLScalarType longScalar =
            ExtendedScalars.newAliasedScalar('Long')
                .aliasedScalar(ExtendedScalars.GraphQLLong)
                .build()
```

See the docs for graphql-java-extended-scalars, and dig into the source code to see how they set up the scalars.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a configuration bean to your project returning a `RuntimeWiringConfigurer` similar to this example for Kotlin.
The documentation only shows you how to return the Configurer but not that you can chain the `scalar` calls and add your own aliases.

```kotlin
package com.sample.config

import graphql.Scalars
import graphql.scalars.ExtendedScalars
import graphql.schema.idl.RuntimeWiring
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.RuntimeWiringConfigurer

@Configuration
class SampleGraphQlConfig {

    @Bean
    fun runtimeWiringConfigurer(): RuntimeWiringConfigurer {
        // add alias `AnotherScalar` for `String`
        val AnotherScalar = ExtendedScalars.newAliasedScalar("AnotherScalar")
            .aliasedScalar(Scalars.GraphQLString)
            .build()

        return RuntimeWiringConfigurer {
                wiringBuilder: RuntimeWiring.Builder ->
            wiringBuilder
                // add BigDecimal scalar
                .scalar(ExtendedScalars.GraphQLBigDecimal)
                // Add long scalar
                .scalar(ExtendedScalars.GraphQLLong)
                // add AnotherScalar scalar
                .scalar(AnotherScalar)
        }
    }
}
```